# Adding Visualforce Page To Sites

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

An org I work with utizilizes the sites feature to expose a number of visualforce pages to end users. I'm trying to create a new visualforce page to expose through the same site. When I view the page using the standard url http://[salesforce_instance].com/apex/[page_name] the page loads fine. When I try to view it through the sites url http://[site_url]/[page_name] I get an authorization required error.

I think that I have to make the page available to the site to display as per [these instructions](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_site_pages.htm) on managing visualforce pages on sites. When I go to edit the site in the org, however, there are no "Add and Remove buttons to enable or disable Visualforce pages for your site". I'm an administrator in the organization. Anything else I have to do to see these buttons? Is this feature in a new place? Am I barking up the wrong tree? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have added step by step diagram incase something you are doing wrong to help you

Comment: I am so thick! I didn't realize that the site label column text was in fact a hyperlink and thus kept hitting the edit button as a way to view the site. Thanks for helping out!